# Random script error. in Angular Unit/Integration Tests

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have the following problem:
When I run unit/integration tests for my Angular project with Karma, there is like a 50:50 chance that my tests will succeed/fail. Mostly it works on my maschine (:D), but not on our build server and that makes it really unreliable at all.

When it fails, it is always a cryptic error message, which says

> **script error.**

...nothing more. Now the strange thing about it is, that it is always another test which fails.

**Here is what I already did or had a look at:**

- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1268
- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/543
- I do not have circular dependencies (at least ng build/serve doesn't complain about it)
- I figured out, that It could be linked to a cross-origin-policy violation, but I actually don't trigger XHR's or lazy load other stuff (at least I think so)

**These are my dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.4.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^6.0.0-beta.16",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.9",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^6.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "devextreme": "^18.1.4",
    "devextreme-angular": "^18.1.4",
    "i": "^0.3.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ngx-scrollbar": "^2.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "npm": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.4.2",
    "fs-extra": "^6.0.1",
    "git-describe": "^4.0.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-param": "^1.0.3",
    "gulp-run": "^1.7.1",
    "hogan.js": "^3.0.2",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "karma": "^2.0.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "license-checker": "^20.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.2.0",
    "markdown-include": "^0.4.3",
    "prettier": "^1.13.7",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "readline-sync": "^1.4.9",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "stylelint": "^9.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-scss": "^3.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.1.3",
    "ts-node": "^6.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "yargs": "^11.1.0"
  }
```

What should I do next ??

I appreciate every hint...thanks

Comment: Also if I run the test command with --source-map false, I do not get a helpful stacktrace..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **finally fixed** the issue.

I somehow came on the right track and figured out, which test fails or rather is causing other tests to fail.

```
// causing part in the tests
beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FilterSidebarComponent);
   component = fixture.componentInstance;
   component.data = {} as DataClass;
   fixture.detectChanges();
 });
```

The problem was now, that inside a subscription in the component, I call a specific method of the class `DataClass`:

```
this.attributeXY.subscribe(event => {
    this.data.reset(); <-- reset() was undefined
    if (event) {
     // do something 
     ...
    }
  })
```

**The remaining question now is, why the cast of the empty object didn't work in this case?** 
My expectation was, that the method `reset()`would be inferred as well

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, many times such random errors are due to a dirty state one of the test left behind which in turn fails some other test. 
AFAIK the default order for Karma is not expected or defined.
I would try to comment out (binary search style) the first half of the tests and see if it passes consistently.